# How to use JQuery post method

Tags: jquery

```
$.post('image.php', {
    image:form.image.value  
}


<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="image" name="image"/>
```

PHP->`isset($_FILES['file'])`

How to use `$.post()` to post **`$_FILES`** inside of form tag?
Do I still need include `enctype`
or do I need use AJAX, and how can I do that?

Comment: sorry, it's impossible - safety reasons

Comment: @picios It's not impossible, anymore. But, is limited to [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski yes, but if you're developer, you don't want to do such things

Comment: i have email and password need to check and post back, hmm... this is going to be hard

Comment: @BenWong Don't be discouraged!  We will help you!

Comment: thx a lot! let me read that post and think how can I achieve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use jQuery form plugin to AJAX submit the form with files.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

In JS

```
$('#form').ajaxSubmit({
 success: function(response) {
  console.log(response);
 } 
});
```

in PHP

```
// after doing upload work etc

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode(['message' => 'Some message or param whatever']);
die();
```

Full docs and examples: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

Comment: if i use plug in, how to post message back from php?

Comment: It's treated as a normal AJAX call - I'll edit the answer to show you how

Comment: thx a lot! let me try it

Answer (score 0):

Just [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) the form!

```
$('form#form').submit();
```

For AJAX Upload read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614)

Comment: he's talking about ajax post

Comment: Maybe after changing his question. Thanks for downvote.